# jQuery Mobile - pageinit and pagecreate only firing once

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on my first jQuery Mobile project and have encountered a roadblock. I am using Version 1.0 and so far the project is very simple, three pages with script only on the index. I incorrectly used `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` at first and then read in the documentation that the correct thing to do is bind `pageinit` or `pagecreate`. Here is the script I am working with for testing purposes (straight off of the docs):

```
$("#main").live('pageinit', function(event) {
        alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});
```

I have tried this both as an external JS file and a script within the `#main` DIV, as suggested in some older threads I've found on here. This works when the index is loaded the first time, but when the user navigates to another page and then returns (revisits), it does not fire again.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried pageinit?

Comment: Yes, tried both pageinit and pagecreate.. sorry, the code I copied & pasted was my latest attempt with pagecreate.. editing

Comment: what browser are you testing against ?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome at the moment..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`pageshow` will fire each time a page is shown, either on the initial page-load or when the user navigates away and then navigates back to that page.

Here is an example of using `pageshow` to run code on each view of a page: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/DHeva/ (Note that this code is being run just before the closing `</body>` tag and is not encapsulated in a `$(document.ready(function () {...});` function).

Here is a documentation link for jQuery Mobile Events (which clearly explain when each of them fires): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html (about half-way down the page starts the *page* events).

Comment: greath answer,good to include the fiddle +1000 from me if i had

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the pageinit event only to assign event handlers to the UI (that happens only one time when it actually gets created), and pagebeforeshow to update the UI - i.e. refresh data, update time, etc....    This latter event will be called EVERYTIME the user switches to that page (by .changepage() or link or browser reload).

Answer (score 0):

pageinit only fires when the page is first loaded.
The index page is never unloaded (even when you navigate elsewhere), so it will never fire that event agian.

Try the pagechange event, which fires whenever the page is changed.