# Correctly calling javascript per-page with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a few pages made with jquery mobile. These pages are all separate files, such as register.php. Each file has one "page", as in the literal jquery mobile `div.page`.

When I click a link, ajax calls this new file and extracts the div.page -- rather than loading the new page like a standard link would.

I have a function, which was originally bound to the onload event for a specific page (register.php). Now, because it's being pulled in with ajax instead of loading a new page, the javascript for that page never fires.

I need to use pageinit() or pagecreate() according to JQM docs - but they don't explain how to do this...

I need to bind one of those events, probably pagecreate as I need to use my function after all elements are ready. But how do I distinguish one page from another using the same script?

If I have a link to `register.js` in my `<head>` for register.php only, it isn't even used when pulled in via ajax - because it only pulls in the `<body>`.

Let's say I have a function called `register_form()`. How do I call this every time `register.php` is opened? This includes clicking the back button.

I looked here, [jQuery Mobile - pageinit and pagecreate only firing once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271415/jquery-mobile-pageinit-and-pagecreate-only-firing-once). However, when you go to a different page the ID of the new page is not added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's (unless they've changed it since I last used jqm)...

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function (e) {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: Ah... pageshow looks like the event I was looking for. And the 2nd argument is an array, one of the elements is (dataUrl (string)
The filtered version of absUrl to be used when identifying the page).

Comment: Actually, this only works if you navigate to the page. What if it should be called when you land directly on the page?

Comment: I believe `pageshow` fires whenever the page is displayed.  The way jQM works is once a page has been viewed once it permanently caches it for that session.  If it's shown again that's where `pageshow` is fired another time.  If you only want to run something the first time the page is shown `pageinit` should be the one you want.